# Xpath attribute value check with a variable passed using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

just a quick question, was trying different ways to accomplish this, but ended with no success. I am trying to check attribute value using xpath and if the attribute value matches, I change the parameters for that tag in xml.

This works:

```
$obj= $xml->xpath('/document/item[@id = "a12sd"]');
```

This does not work, because I need to pass the value via a variable to check with the attribute value

```
$checkID = "a12sd";

$obj= $xml->xpath('/document/item[@id = $checkID]');
```

Any suggestions how I can rectify this problem.

EDIT:

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document>
    <item id="a12sd">       
        <name>James</name>
        <pdf>0023.pdf</pdf>
    </item>
    <item id="rdf23">       
        <name>Alex</name>
        <pdf>0178.pdf</pdf>
    </item>
    <item id="2we34">       
        <name>Tom</name>
        <pdf>0886.pdf</pdf>
    </item>
    <item id="123de">       
        <name>Robby</name>
        <pdf>1239.pdf</pdf>
    </item>
</document>
```

PHP Code:

```
$id = "a12sd";
$xml = simplexml_load_file('items.xml');  

$who_is_who = $xml->xpath('/document/item[@id = "a12sd"]');             

$who_is_who[0]->name = "Arnold";

$xml->asXml("items.xml");
```

Thanks

Comment: Try putting the variable within quotes like you did on your first line: `[@id = "$checkID"]`

Comment: @Tino, did as you advised, but getting errors

Comment: It would be helpful to know which errors exactly ;)

Comment: Use `$obj= $xml->xpath('/document/item[@id="'.$checkID.'"]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$obj= $xml->xpath('/document/item[@id="'.$checkID.'"]');`

```
<?php
$id = "a12sd";
$xml = simplexml_load_file('items.xml');  

$who_is_who = $xml->xpath('/document/item[@id = "'.$id.'"]');             

$who_is_who[0]->name = "Arnold";

$xml->asXml("items.xml");

?>
```

Comment: thanks Pushpesh, you saved my day one more time and I didn't realize it, that it can be done like that, thanks for pointing it out