# Access and update attribute value in XML using XPath and PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

this is an extension to my previous post today which can be found here: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099208/xpath-attribute-value-check-with-a-variable-passed-using-php)

Now I want to access another attribute based upon the id attribute and change that as well. Here is my modified xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document>
    <item id="a12sd">       
        <name>James</name>
        <age years="25"/>
        <pdf>0023.pdf</pdf>
    </item>
    <item id="rdf23">       
        <name>Alex</name>
        <age years="35"/>
        <pdf>0178.pdf</pdf>
    </item>
    <item id="2we34">       
        <name>Tom</name>
        <age years="25"/>
        <pdf>0886.pdf</pdf>
    </item>
    <item id="123de">       
        <name>Robby</name>
        <age years="28"/>
        <pdf>1239.pdf</pdf>
    </item>
</document>
```

I have been able to update the tags using this code:

```
$id = "a12sd";
$xml = simplexml_load_file('items.xml');  

$itemsList = $xml->xpath('/document/item[@id = "a12sd"]');             

$itemsList[0]->name = "Arnold";

$xml->asXml("items.xml");
```

Now I need to access the attribute age for the id="a12sd" and update the age to say: 26

Any idea how I can reach that attribute for given id and change that value.

Note: before changing the value the user knows only the "id" value, so based upon id value I want to change years attribute for that particular id.

Thanks

Comment: I assume actually valid xml (`<age years="35"/>` for instance)?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, xml data updated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$itemsList[0]->age->attributes()->years = 26;
```